# Pulling From Master -- git

Tags: eclipse, git

I have a project with lots of merge problems and I just want to get everything that's in the master and discard my local stuff. How can I do this in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the console its much easier. To reset all your actual changes you can do:

```
git checkout .
```

If you have some commits between the master and your actual position. You have to reset the master hard to the origin master.

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Perhaps you should have a look at

[Git in 15 Minutes](http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1)